# Как использовать метод arrey.find js

Tags: javascript

```
function Microwave() {
  this.dishes = [{ nameOfDish: 'potato', time: 30 }, { nameOfDish: 'pizza', time: 45 }]
}

Microwave.prototype.cookDish = function (nameOfDish) {


this.disches.find(function(currentValue, index, arr){
})
};
const microwave = new Microwave( );
microwave.cookDish('potato')
```

исходя из значения time будет запускать таймер и по истечении оного - выводить алерт. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: _Как это можно реализовать?_ - нужно найти нужный элемент, взять значение его поля `time`, и передать его вторым параметром в функцию [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)

Comment: Не стоит полностью менять текст вопроса, особенно после получения ответа

Answer (score 1):

```js
function Microwave() {
  this.dishes = [{
    nameOfDish: 'potato',
    time: 30
  }, {
    nameOfDish: 'pizza',
    time: 45
  }]
}

Microwave.prototype.cookDish = function(nameOfDish) {
  this.dishes.find(function(currentValue, index, arr) {
    if(currentValue.nameOfDish === nameOfDish){
      myAlert(currentValue);
      return true;
    }
  });
};

function myAlert(obj){
  setTimeout(_ => console.info(`Name: ${obj.nameOfDish}; Time: ${obj.time}`), obj.time);
}
const microwave = new Microwave();
microwave.cookDish('potato')
```

Answer (score 1):

Метод [`.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) возвращает элемент массива, для которого переданная функция-callback вернет `true`.

Для поиска элемента по свойству `nameOfDish` можно использовать следующую функцию:

```
(dish) => dish.nameOfDish == nameOfDish;
```

Далее взять у найденного объекта свойство `time`, и использовать его в качестве второго параметра для функции [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout), который задает время задержки в миллисекундах.

вызов [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) для найденного элемента может выглядеть так

```
setTimeout(alert, dish.time, dish.nameOfDish);
```

Если подразумевалось, что значение свойства time - это секунду, то перед передачей в качестве параметра стоит привести их к миллисекундам, для этого умножив на 1000.

Все в сборе может выглядеть так:

```js
function Microwave() {
  this.dishes = [{
    nameOfDish: 'potato',
    time: 1000
  }, {
    nameOfDish: 'pizza',
    time: 45
  }]
}

Microwave.prototype.cookDish = function(nameOfDish) {
  var dish = this.dishes.find(dish => dish.nameOfDish == nameOfDish);
  setTimeout(alert, dish.time, dish.nameOfDish);
};
const microwave = new Microwave();
microwave.cookDish('potato')
```